# cant create peer to peer with apprtc and apprtcdemo for android

Tags: webrtc

I have installed the apprtc python application in my linux server, its ok when trying to connect between browsers, but when I'm trying to create peer2peer with the apprtcdemo app for android, I get this error in my channel.html "the provided token is no valid", I see that when   I change the android app url https://apprtc.appspot.com/?r= to a custom domain , its weird because if I just use the first url it works...

Could someone help me with that?

Tks very much

Comment: Hi -- do you mean you've used the code from the apprtc repo (https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsamples%2Fjs%2Fapprtc) for your own appspot subdomain? When you say 'app for Android', do you mean a web app running in Chrome on Android? Also, just to check, you're getting the token dynamically (not hardcoded in the JavaScript)?

Comment: Hi tks for you time. Yeah Im using that web app for my own domain, and I'm trying to make it work with ApprtcDemo for android, its a native app here is it (http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/talk/examples/android/), and yes the token is getting dynamically

Comment: do you know about some example where use Apprtc Demo with a custom server? I have tried a lot but not success.... really appreciate it

Comment: You should be able to use the source code from https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsamples%2Fjs%2Fapprtc. An alternative is to use something like Socket.io for signaling, as on http://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab.

Comment: Hi I have used source code from google and its running with apprtcdemo for android, but only in production... and that have channel limits... I have tried in development mode but I got cross domain issues while trying to create channel in the channel.html stored in the android app, the error is in the jsapi.js when its doing request to the python server, I have tried allowing cross domain in python but does not work, do you know how can I run in development mode? tks

Answer (score 2):

There are two android apk available for WebRTC, `appRtcDemo` and `webRtcDemo`. `appRtcDemo` apk can be used for android device to browser connectivity. You need to provide room id to connect to one room. If you are the room initiator then you have to enter -1.
If you want to connect two android device then you have to compile and install `webRtcDemo` apk. This apk interface provide place to enter ip address of another device and vice versa then both device will be connected. 
Please go through `http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started` for more information. Both the apks i've compiled and installed and checked how it works.

Comment: ,did you successfully make a call between 2 android devices with webrtcdemo??, because all i'm getting is the feed from the same device. even when i enter the ip of the second device in the settings -> remote ip address. do you have any suggestion on what i need to do the get the call working properly? thank you.

Comment: I was able to make calls successfully between two android device using webrtcdemo. But I tested using WLAN of my office network. I did not use it further because I was using apprtcdemo for app reference. My suggestion is when you enter remote ip in webrtcdemo,just check if loop-back is unchecked. I guess for you loop-back is enabled, so you are receiving your own video packet, though you have entered remote ip. Make sure loop-back is disabled while making call.